# Why this (mis)use of Java generics doesn't compile?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won't this generic java code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile)

Given the following code:

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ComeGetSome {
  //TODO: private final Some<?> some = new Some();
  private final Some some = new Some();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ComeGetSome().dude();
  }

  public void dude() {
    for (String str : some.getSomeStrings()) { //FIXME: does not compile!
      System.out.println(str);
    }
  }
}

class Some<T> {
  public List<String> getSomeStrings() {
    return Collections.<String> emptyList();
  }
}
```

It does not compile because `some.getSomeStrings()` returns a raw `List`. But the method signature specify that it returns a `List<String>` !

Somehow it relates to the fact that `Some` has a type declaration but is referenced as a raw type. Using a reference to `Some<?>` fixes the problem. But the method has nothing to do with the type declaration on the class!

Why does the compiler behave like that?

Comment: Collections.emptyList<String>()??

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661068/java-generics-vanishing-type-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a raw (untyped) instance of a generic class, then it is treated as being *completely* raw, ie all generic type info is ignored, even if the type being ignored is *not* related to the generic type that has been omitted.

That's why this...

```
private final Some<?> some = new Some();
```

...fixes the error - it uses a *typed* version of `Some` (albeit a wildcard one)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, it doesn't make sense to declare the class `Some` generic if you don't actually use the defined type parameter. And that's actually the source of problems. You instantiate the member field of that type in this fasion:

```
private final Some some = new Some();
```

This is a declaration of a **raw** type - that is a generic type with it's type parameters left out. This actually means not only that it's own type parameter `T` is thrown away, but also **all** of the generic types used in that class's methods are ignored, including the `<String>` parameter in `public List<String> getSomeStrings()`.

So the solution is actually simple, quoting Joshua Bloch:

> Don’t use raw types in new code.

To make this concrete, the fix you suggested:

```
private final Some<?> some = new Some();
```

fixes the problem, but actually generates a compiler warning (unchecked operation). The *clean* way would be either declaring an actual type parameter on the right side of the statement, such as:

```
private final Some<String> some = new Some<String>();
```

The type you put in the generic parameter can by any type you want, it depends on the way in which you intend to use the `Some` class. But if you actually don't need the type parameter, simply remove it and the code will work just fine:

```
class Some { ... }
```

A side note: it's not necessary to explicitly declare the `String` parameter in this code:

```
return Collections.<String> emptyList();
```

The compiler infers the generic type from the method signature, so you can simplify the code to this:

```
public List<String> getSomeStrings() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
```

**Edit**:
Speaking of Joshua Bloch, there is a nice Java puzzler regarding this actual matter in his talk at Google I/O 2011 at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbp-3BJWsU8&t=36m04s